# Controlling the number of threads and controlling object accessing in a Multi Threaded Web Crawler in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

I built a web crawler but it is single threaded. Now I am extending it to work with multiple threads. I am not able to understand the following :

1. How many threads should I create? Should it be a fixed number or a dynamic one changing according to the length of the Queue holding the URIs? (Taking into consideration the available memory also)
2. I have created a new class for the thread through the Runnable Interface and I want each thread's `run` method to access an object I created in my Main class which is calling `thread.start()`. How should I access this object from each thread?

I am using NetBeans.

Comment: 1. with using a thread pool, you don't have to carry about the nummber of threads. You can create them depending on current amount of cpus. (for exacter infos, -> anserws)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitely going to want concurrency with a web a crawler :)

And you're probably going to want to set up a thread pool so that you can reuse threads and not bite the cost of instantiating new threads with each task.

The thread pool options that you have are a FixedThreadPool and a CachedThreadPool. the benefits of each of these are explained in detail in the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). The big drawback of the CachedThreadPool is that there's no limit on how many threads can be created; in the event that a very large number of threads are added to the pool, you might see some significant performance degradation or timeouts (if you have a socket timeout defined).

In either case, the best practice for setting up thread pools is through [java.util.concurrent.Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

It's just a matter of creating an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) by calling one of the following:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
```

Once you have the threadpool, you can either invoke a single runnable (which doesn't return a response) or a [callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (which does) by using the submit() method.

You can also run .invokeAll() if you're using callables to generate [futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):

```
futures = cachedThreadPool.invokeAll(tasks,
                                     timeout,
                                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And then get the results:

```
for (Future f: futures) {
   someList.add(f.get())
}
```

If you want multiple threads to be able to modify the same object, you'll either need to use the [synchronized keyword in the setters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) or use [thread-safe data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Hope this helps. Good luck!!

Comment: +1 for highlighting the issue with dynamic pools - a very large number of links could be quickly generated, resulting in a thread explosion.  A fixed pool would be better, (a large one, 'cos the network blocking, but fixed).

Answer (score 4):

For the first question I guess in your situation it's best to use a dynamically adjusting thread pool like:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will
>   reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These
>   pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute
>   many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse
>   previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is
>   available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads
>   that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed
>   from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will
>   not consume any resources.

For the second question, you can create a constructor and pass objects that way:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
     private Object obj;

     public ThreadTask(Object obj) {
         this.obj = obj;
     }

     public void run() {
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Object obj = new Object();
     exec.submit(new ThreadTask(obj));
}
```

Comment: +1 good answer. I would like to recommend to him using a FixedThreadPool however. I guess Crawling is not really that "short-lived". So it might be helpful not to create hundreds of threads at a time even through an ExecutorService.

Comment: @Fildor: I'm not actually very aware on what each task would do in a web crawler. I was under the impression that it just takes a link, extracts the links that it points to, puts them in the global queue and then stops, so that's why I was expecting them to be short-lived.

Comment: Just wanted to add the FixedThreadPool in case it is not-so-short-lived. Did not mean to be offending :) Assuming it _is_ short-lived, your answer is totally correct.

Comment: @Fildor: Ah no, I wasn't offended, sorry if it came out like that. :) I was actually just saying that I'm not really aware about how he implemented his crawler.

Comment: @Tudor. Hey Thanks it helped, fixed pool will be good option in my case. I had doubt in 2nd answer, my Object is going to be very large in size so coping it for each thread will be time taking. Can there be any other option or just pass a pointer to it.

Comment: @Prannoy Mittal: In this version only a reference is passed, not the entire object. There is no copying of data involved. You can use it safely. :)

Answer (score 1):

There could not be any specific answer it. But you can study on following -

*For 1st point study on `ExecutorService and ThreadPoolExecutor`.*

*For 2nd point study on `callable and Future`.*